# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm working on an old MVC project which uses .aspx views. Whenever I run the code I get this runtime error.

[image: Runtime error]

I have checked the references and added System.Web.WebPages.Razor version 2.0.0.0 since I'm unable to find the version mentioned here.

[image: Added reference version 2.0.0.0]

Also, I have added DependentAssembly to the web.config file like below.

[image: web.config change]

But I'm still getting this error and even in the aspx pages I can see this issue. Can someone help me with this? I tried adding asp.net.webpage from NuGet. But I couldn't find it.

[image: view error]

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: Go to Nuget Package Manager (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution ) . Check Updates tab. If update is available then update it. If this doesn't work then remove System.Web.WebPages.Razor reference from your file and re-install it.

Comment: Did you try running `Update-Package -Reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`?

Comment: @noobprogrammer I tried. But there are no updates.

Comment: @Knelis Yes. I tried. References were not added from the package manager console and I tried anyway. Since this is old project framework is not supporting razor latest one.

Comment: @user2837480 try  installing Microsoft.AspNet.Webpages via nuget manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is still looking for an answer for this issue just install ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM framework from here [MVC3 framework](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4211) and that will fix the issue. Once you install it you should be able to see below programs installed under AddOrRemove program (control panel -> program and features)

[image: packages]

Sorry about not to updating the answer soon.